# the highest quantity sold in last month sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a newbie so my knowledge about SQL is not good.

I have 3 tables `orders`, `orderdetail`, `product`. How to query for the best selling product which has the highest quantity sold in last month (the best selling product=product). I'm using SQL Server.

My query is :

```
select 
    OrderDetail.Quantity, Order.Total, Order.Date, Product.Name
from
    OrderDetail, Order, Product 
where 
    max(Quantity)
```

I don't know how to add a condition last month

`Orders`

```
Id, primary key
Date, datetime
total, float
```

`Product`

```
Id, primary key
Name, nvchar(20)
```

`OrderDetail`

```
Id, primary key
price, float
quantity, int
Amount, float
product_Id, int
order_Id, int
```

Comment: Can you show your work / attempt at a result. As it stands this will be closed as not reproducible.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Best way to learn SQL is to practice, practice and practice. Create the tables, add some data and try JOIN's etc, until you get what you want!

Comment: i use sql server. My querry is : select  OrderDetail.Quanlity,Order.Total,Order.Date,
Product.Name 
from OrderDetail,Order,Product
where MAX(Quanlity)

Comment: Why has this been closed? I think the problem is clearly described (get the product which has the highest quantity sold in last month).

Comment: Evolve. No one should be using or leaning to use [old-style joins via the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: cant understood the reason why the posted was closed

Comment: i  described problem very clearly  @@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a join syntax of the 1980s. In 1992 explicit joins got introduced in the SQL standard. Only use explicit joins, never use comma-separated joins.

This is your joins:

```
from OrderDetail, Order, Product
```

There is no criteria on how to join the tables. This means the DBMS is supposed to join every row of OrderDetail with every row of Order and every row of Product. This is not what you want.

You want to join the tables on the keys they are related by:

```
from order o
join orderdetail od on od.order_id = o.id
join product p on p.id = od.product_id
```

And well, the condition

```
where MAX(Quanlity)
```

just makes no sense. A condition is a boolean expression where you usually compare things. One thing to do here is to limit the rows to last month. This alone is not trivial. There are many approaches to do this, here is a slow one:

```
where year(o.date) * 12 + month(o.date) = year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate()) - 1
```

To get quantities per month requires aggreation. Per product translates to `GROUP BY product_id` here. To get the top product, use `TOP` (with the appropriate `ORDER BY`).

```
select top(1) with ties
  product_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity
from order o
join orderdetail od on od.order_id = o.id
where year(o.date) * 12 + month(o.date) = year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate()) - 1
group by product_id
order by total_quantity desc;
```

Comment: very helpful to me especially how to writing clause right ways. Thank you with all my heart <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   select Name ,total_qty from product p ,
   (select product_id,sum(quantity) as total_qty from orderdetail od,order o
   where o.id=od.order_id and  date_trunc('month',o.date) = 
   date_trunc('month',now()::date -interval '1 month')  group by product_id order by 
   total_qty desc limit 1) a
   where a.product_id=p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @datastart date, @dataend date
SELECT @datastart=DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))
SELECT @dataend=DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)))

select sum(od.quantity) as Qtty, od.product_id, p.name 
from orderdetail od 
left join order o on od.orderid=o.id
left join product p on od.product_id=p.id
where o.date between @datastart and @dataend
group by od.product_id, p.name
order by Qtty desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Name` from `product` INNER JOIN `order_details` ON `product`.`id`= `order_details`.`product_id` INNER JOIN `order` ON `order_details`.`order_id` = `order`.`id` WHERE MONTH(`order`.`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY `product`.`id`ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

> **Order** is reserved keyword in SQL so here I answered using order because it is mentioned in your question. but please change the name of the table Order.

Hope you will get your answer or atleast idea.[image]

you can use this query result with your variable as the *best selling product=product*